# Flyway 4.0 upgrade failed on Amazon Redshift database - FlywaySqlScriptException

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, flyway

I've been using Flyway 3.2.1 (database migration framework) on a Redshift DB with no problems. Tried to upgrade to Flyway 4.0 and got the exception shown below.

Anyone else encountered this & have ideas on how to fix it, before I go spelunking into the source code?

```
org.flywaydb.core.internal.dbsupport.FlywaySqlScriptException: 
Script failed
-------------
SQL State  : XX000
Error Code : 500310
Message    : [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: cannot insert/update into table after dropping non-nullable column;
Line       : 20
Statement  : UPDATE "public"."schema_version" SET "version_temp"="version"
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.dbsupport.SqlScript.execute(SqlScript.java:117) 
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.metadatatable.MetaDataTableImpl.upgradeIfNecessary(MetaDataTableImpl.java:79)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.execute(Flyway.java:1356)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:917)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please file an issue in the issue tracker.

As a workaround you can also drop the schema_version table and (re-)baseline the DB.

Comment: Thanks - good to know there's a workaround, although we'd like to avoid doing that if possible. Filed an issue per your request: [upgrading AWS Redshift DB from Flyway 3.2.1 to 4.0 failed - couldn't upgrade metadata table #1231](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/1231) .

Answer (score 0):

Good news is that this has been fixed in Flyway 4.0.1 ([issue #1231](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/pull/1256)). Thanks go to Axel Fontaine and Nathan Vick.